# Can't push_front() a standard library list with my objects in C++

Tags: c++, stdlist

I have an class and I would like to use the standard library list to store a list of them. I essentially want to push_front() the list. So my code is like this:

```
#include <list>
/* ... lots of stuff ...*/

complexNode myObject();

std::list<complexNode> complexList();

myList.push_front(myObject);
```

But the compiler throws this error:

error: request for member ‘push_front’ in ‘complexList’, which is of non-class type ‘std::list<complexNode, std::allocator<complexNode> > ()()’

The class complexNode has a copy contructor.

I really don't understand the problem and what that error actually means... please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::list<complexNode> complexList();
```

shouldn't this be :

```
std::list<complexNode> complexList; // without the ()
```

Comment: Yes, with the empty () it's interpreted as a function declaration (!), even if it's in local scope.

Comment: Yes, if you use "std::list<complexNode> complexList();" the compiler thinks you are declaring a function complexList() returning a std::list<complexNode>.

Comment: @lothar: "the compiler thinks you are declaring a function". The compiler is correct ;-p

Comment: @onebyone: Yes, the user "thinks" he is declaring a variable and the compiler knows better ;-) This is a very common pitfall, though and IMHO the compilers should issue a warning if the user tries to "forward declare" a function inside a codeblock, as usually the user made a mistake and meant to declare a variable.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
std::list<complexNode> complexList();
```

Has the common name "[C++'s most vexing parse](http://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&hs=A0w&q=c%2B%2B+most+vexing+parse&btnG=Search&meta=)". In short, you have made `complexList` be the declaration of a function that returns a list, instead of a local variable. Remove the `()`, then it cannot be parsed as a function.